# Find calls that specify a non-default value for an optional method parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search

I have a method:

```
public void MyMethod(Foo foo, int? optionalInt = null) {
    // code I don't care about here
}
```

What I want to do is to find all calls to the method that specify a value for optionalInt. The method has over 200 references. If it's the only way, I'll go through them, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that a partial answer is to delete the parameter and see where there are build errors. This is not always applicable, however. For example, if the parameter is part of an interface, there will also be build errors that are not related to what I want to find. For another example, if there are multiple such parameters, and this is not the last one, deleting it may not be so easy.